# CGO build go file with cygwin and openssl

Tags: go, gcc, openssl, cgo

Im trying to compile some go code containing some C and make use of openssl library. Im one windows and Im using cygwin64 for the gcc compiler and openssl devel library. However when I run the command I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: could not find -lmingwex
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: could not find -lmingw32
```

However when I look in cygwin I cannot find lmingw32 or lmingwex. Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated in [`ziglang/zig` issue 7874](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/7874), I would test first if the same Go/C code could be compiled, from a git bash (which use msys2, no Cygwin) using [ziglang](https://ziglang.org/)

```
CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CC="zcc" CXX="zc++" go build main.go
```

With, in the `%PATH%`

```sh
zcc

#!/bin/sh
zig cc -target x86_64-windows-gnu $@

zc++

#!/bin/sh
zig c++ -target x86_64-windows-gnu $@
```

You can also follow "[Using Zig on Windows with msys2 toolchain](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/wiki/Using-Zig-on-Windows-with-msys2-toolchain)"

The [OP Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10456651/thomas) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69234087/cgo-build-go-file-with-cygwin-and-openssl/69249890#comment122641485_69249890):

> I used the following command:
>
> CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build main.go
>
> , and it worked ;)

Comment: Then use $PATH, instead of %PATH%

Comment: I dont understand PATH things... Is it possible you can explain it for a dummy?

Comment: @Thomas Your scripts (or the ones I mention in the answer) must be in one of the folders of your Windows %PATH% (which is also used in your cygwin $PATH): https://superuser.com/a/155687/141 (PATH in general: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: I used the following command: CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64  go build main.go, and it worked ;)
Thanks for the help, could not have done it without you

Comment: @Thomas Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.